# how to get date picker and time picker display on main screen

Tags: android

I am new to Android Studio programming and I have 0 experience. I need some help and any help will be very much appreciated!

I'm trying to make the datepicker and timepicker show on the main screen textview but I have absolutely no idea how to do it. I did check on the questions section but it didn't help.

Basically now I only have the date and time picker on the main screen with the textview below.

How can I go about doing it? I'm sorry if it sounds to newbie but I really want to do it as I want to help my friend and at the same time learn.

please help. Thank bunches!

[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE9HO.jpg)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you mean actually you have date and time picker, and a textView. Your problem is do not know how to add Listener which can set data to textView after choose date and time.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question - post a comment if you want clarification from the poster.

Comment: Hi and yes! I need to add a listener and have it shown at the "New text" area.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use WheelView, please check below refrences.

[android-aresanal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/142)

[Picker view](https://github.com/alafighting/CharacterPickerView)

[Wheel View](https://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=811211D4FC4E6FD4EB4CC4BB3B7E8E8C?recipeId=883)

[Wheel View](https://github.com/wangjiegulu/WheelView)

Comment: Thanks all for the help! really Appreciate it!